# How to fetch Json value and fill it on dataset in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to fetch JSON value but failed to retrieve value and fill on `DataSet` and bind them on `GridView` and I am getting null value.

Here I have tried code please seen below:

```
var outputValue = cpmu.getCPMUdata(AgreementNo, AgreementedBy, YearOfAgreement);
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(outputValue);

var data = obj["data"];

StringReader theReader = new StringReader(data);
DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);

var result = theDataSet.Tables[0];

Label3.Text = theDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("AgreementNo");                                   
Label2.Text = theDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("Agreementby");
Label4.Text = theDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("YearofAgreement");

GridView2.DataSource = theDataSet;
GridView2.DataMember = theDataSet.Tables["Bill"].ToString();
GridView2.DataBind();
```

**JSON** code:

```
public string getCPMUdata(string AgreementNo, string Agreementby, string YearofAgreement)
{
    //Code to accept the SSL server certificate
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

    //Configuration Values
    string strbaseUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseUrl"];
    string strLoginBaseUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginBaseUrl"];
    String username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
    string password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
    //***************

    /* Input Values */
    string strAgreementNo = AgreementNo;
    string strAgreementby = Agreementby;
    string strYearofAgreement = YearofAgreement;
    /****************/

    // Initialize the response
    string returnvalue = string.Empty;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    HttpWebRequest request = null;
    String responseText = null;
    String authorization;

    try
    {
        //Create the Request Url
        String requestUrl = strLoginBaseUrl + "?service=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(strbaseUrl + "/3DSpace/resources/CHiPSCPMSBillDetailsModeler/CHiPSCPMSBillDetails?AgreementNo=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strAgreementNo) + "&Agreementby=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strAgreementby) + "&YearofAgreement=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strYearofAgreement));

        request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        authorization = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        if (request.HaveResponse == true && response == null)
        {
            String msg = "response was not returned or is null";
            throw new WebException(msg);
        }

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            String msg = "response with status: " + response.StatusCode + " " + response.StatusDescription;
            throw new WebException(msg);
        }

        // get the first HTTP response content
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //extract the LT code from the response string
        String lt = "";
        lt = responseText.Substring(responseText.LastIndexOf("\"lt\""));
        lt = lt.Substring(0, lt.IndexOf(","));
        lt = lt.Replace("\"lt\":", ",");
        lt = lt.Replace("\"", "");
        lt = lt.Replace("\"", "");
        lt = lt.Replace(",", "");

        //Extract Session ID from the response header
        String strJsonId = "";
        strJsonId = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
        strJsonId = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"].Substring(strJsonId.LastIndexOf("JSESSIONID"));
        strJsonId = strJsonId.Substring(0, strJsonId.IndexOf(";"));
        strJsonId = strJsonId.Replace("JSESSIONID", "");
        strJsonId = strJsonId.Replace("=", "");
        strJsonId = strJsonId.Trim();

        //throw exception if access token or sessionid is not available
        if (lt == "" && strJsonId == "")
        {
            String msg = "Unable to retrieve Access Token and session Key";
            throw new WebException(msg);
        }

        //Second HTTP Request to get the Data based on the 'lt' token, 'SessionID' and Query String parameters
        WebRequest requestLast = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        requestLast.Headers.Add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + strJsonId);
        requestLast.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "lt=" + lt + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        requestLast.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        requestLast.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream1 = requestLast.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream1.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream1.Close();

        // Get the response.
        WebResponse responseLast = requestLast.GetResponse();
        dataStream1 = responseLast.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(dataStream1);
        returnvalue = reader1.ReadToEnd();

        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        reader1.Close();
        dataStream1.Close();
        response.Close();
        responseLast.Close();

    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Response != null)
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            returnvalue = response.StatusCode + " " + response.StatusDescription;
        }
        else
        {
            returnvalue = e.Message;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
    }
    return returnvalue;
}

     public static bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
     {
         return true;
     }
}
```

Here in variable `returnvalue`, I get such type of error:

> {"msg":"error","data":"  NA
>   </AgreementNo> NA </Agreementby>  NA
>   </YearofAgreement>    \t\t        No Data Found\t\t
>   </Bill>\t\t </xml>"}

Comment: your JSON structure might help

Comment: as mentioned, please show the JSON structure. We need to know what the input looks like.

Comment: fetch the value of agreement_no, agreement_by and year_of_agreement from database and pass them into JSON object and serialize & Deserialize them.

Comment: from start to end, every line works properly but at the end of                              " StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(dataStream1);
               returnvalue = reader1.ReadToEnd(); "                                                                  it didn't return any value and show message as shown below:                                                               {"msg":"error","data":" NA </AgreementNo> NA </Agreementby> NA </YearofAgreement> \t\t No Data Found\t\t
</Bill>\t\t </xml>"}

Comment: so you're not getting a NULL value, you're getting a valid response from the remote server. It just happens to be a response which tells you that the server found no actual data to return. That's not the same as the _response itself_ being NULL. Btw...the remote service appears to be wrapping XML inside JSON...that's just...weird. Choose a format and use it. Mixing the two is bizarre and bit pointless. You have to deserialise the JSON and then deserialise the XML within it as well. If everything was one or the other it would be much simpler.

Comment: Anyway back to the issue at hand...if the remote service is not returning the data you expected, then you have to look there for the problem. It's not the fault of the code above, unless you are sending it parameter values which mean its query doesn't match any data. Since we don't know what parameter values you're sending, or what the remote query criteria are, or what's in the remote database, we can't help you with that unfortunately. You'll have to check your values, check the logic of the remote service and the available data, and make sure it all matches up as you intended.

Comment: getCPMUdata() applied on the 'ddl' control due to this it return NA value but when the method applied on the page_load () then return passing value. why?

Comment: I have no idea, since I can't see the context of those two calls. I would guess maybe you're passing different parameter values in each case. That would be an obvious way to make it return different results. Have you tried to debug it to see what values you send for each parameter? Like I already said, just looking at the code itself doesn't enable us to know what actual data values you are using when you run the code. And even if we did, we don't know what the remote server does with them, so we still wouldn't be able to tell you if they were correct things to send, or not.

Comment: all data value that are send to JSON object is correct i.e agreement_value, agreement_by & Year_of_agreement. I think "StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(dataStream1);" didn't fetch the proper data but why, didn't get right now. Because above uploaded code works proper on page_load event but doesn't work on dropdown list event.

Comment: Well, think about it logically: `StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(dataStream1);` gets executed exactly the same in both cases. So why would that be the issue? All it does it read what the remote service returns. What the remote service returns is, I assume, affected in part or in whole by the parameters you pass into it. So, you say you call getCPMUdata() from two different locations. Exactly the same code within getCPMUdata() will run each time. The only possible difference can be the values you pass into it. Are you 100% **certain** you send the same values in each of the 2 cases?

Comment: Try visiting the same URL direct in your browser, or using PostMan, with the variable values you think you're sending via C#, and see what you get back. Then experiment with different values to see what effect it has on the response. BTW you're not sending a JSON object, you're sending querystring parameters as per the content of requestURL. A GET request has no body so you can't send JSON, despite what you set for the contentType. You're _receiving_ JSON (bizarrely with XML wrapped inside it), but that's a totally separate affair.

Comment: sir, when I have passed sample data i.e test data for 3 given variable then it works properly but when I have given different value other than test data and applied getCPMUdata() either in page_load event or in ddl_select event it return exactly same value i.e NA

Comment: There you go then. Changing the values affects the response. So you need to ensure you pass correct values. If you're expecting a different response back from the server when you passed these non-sample values, then you need to fix the server code. Again, as I've said more than once already, we can't see that code and we don't know what it's supposed to do, so we can't fix it for you. The information in your question here is insufficient to reproduce your problem. You're focusing on the wrong area of your system, in my opinion.

Comment: ok sir. Can you tell me please, how to get JSON Object inside dropdown control event. Is there another way to initialize or defined dropdown list control id?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your dropdown and its events, because, again, _I can't see the relevant code_ ...but anyway it sounds like perhaps a separate question. It's not really clear what exactly you mean just from such a short description. Maybe delete this question, since it's going nowhere, and ask a new one focused on the code which actually has the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I would push my json to an object-model (poco objects) and then convert the poco object(s) to a dataset.    json -> ICollection<Employee> emps and then convert the ICollection<Employee> emps to a dataset.  THen you can see where any break down occurs more easily.